# Confusion with margin-top alignment with a percentage value

Tags: css, layout, margin, html, percentage

I've been trying to get a handle on fluid layouts in CSS with percentages and thought I was getting somewhere until I ran into this problem while testing out some things. With the code below I have two divs that **should** be placed right outside of view, so that if you scroll at all you should see them right away.

The one aligned with the left margin works perfectly, but the div aligned with the top margin has results that fumble me. To get the desired result I had to set the top margin to 42%, and I'm not sure where this number is coming from. I figured it would be 90% (100% - topbar's height), and at first I thought it might have something to do with the browser interface being included but there's no way my interface is 48% and putting the browser in fullscreen didn't fix it. What really gets me is that setting navigation's height to 90% plus topbar's height to 10% perfectly fits in view as expected, so why is the height-wise margin different?

Help is greatly appreciated, and I'd love it if you could try to explain anything as much as possible since I'm still trying to understand these attributes and how they work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body, html {
    background-color:#988557;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0%;
}
#topbar {
    margin-left:100%;
    background-color:#3F4A66;
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
}
#navigation {
    margin-top:42%;
    background-color:#3F4A66;
    width:10%;
    height:90%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="topbar">
</div>
<div id="navigation">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's hard to imagine what you are trying to achieve, could you add a simple image with the divs represented by simple rectangles to give a visual impression of the layout you are after?

Comment: I apologize as I may not have stated it very clearly, but I'm not trying to fix anything, rather I'm trying to understand **why** the margin-top is 42% rather than 90% to make the navigation div appear just out of view. Especially when the margin-left value as well as the width/height values of the divs are working without a strange number like 42%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your magic 42% comes from the fact that margins in percentages are calculated based on the containing block's **width**. So the top margin that you have specified is 42% of the width of the block that is containing your #navigation div, in this case the `body`.

Have a look at the [w3c specification for margin](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties) in percentages.

I think what you mean with `margin-top: 90%` is: Add as much space to the top of #navigate equal to 90% of the viewport **height**.
What the browser does is: Add space as much space to the top op #navigate equal to 90% of the viewport **width**.

If you make your browser viewport exactly square you will see that the 90% does exactly what you want. However, if you make the viewport rectangular, which is more common, you will see that the positioning is off, conforming to "percentage of width" instead of "percentage of height".

Comment: But I set body's height to 100%, which is as I understand it stretching body to 100% of the browser page. So 42% of the body would be literally 42% of the page, which wouldn't push it off like it does. This logic works perfectly for width and margin-left involving the div topbar, so why is it different for height and margin-top involving the div navigation?

Comment: The confusion lies in the fact that it takes 42% of the **width** of the page in pixels and uses that value as the `margin-top` for #navigate. So it uses a percentage of the **X-axis** to adjust the **Y-axis**. If you make your browser viewport exactly square you will see that your expected 90% does what you want. But because people rarely browse with square browsers you'll end up with confusion like yours.

Comment: Well I'm trying to do this for a fluid layout, one that can resize between different resolutions and browser sizes. From what you're saying though my layout won't be preserved if they're in a different aspect ratio from me. Is there another way to do this then, because from what I understand from what you're saying is if someone made their window very long with a small height, layouts meant to be on the bottom of the window will be way scrolled down.

Comment: You can use absolute positioning, if you put something at `top:100%` it will always be exactly outside the viewport at the bottom, regardless of the resolution.

Comment: Thank you very much! With absolute positioning it's now working as I first expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

It is consider a good practice to use a Pixel for margins instead of using percent..

Comment: What??? Where did you get that idea? I don't believe there is any guideline that agrees with that anywhere in the world. Would you please add a reference that supports this argument?

Comment: As I said, I am trying to do fluid layouts, which is to my knowledge impossible to do or at least much harder to do with pixels.